# Status call back not working in twilio

Tags: php, twilio

Iam using twilio Programmable voice  while trying to Tracking the call status of an outbound call and save it log whether the user answer or cut the call ,but the problem i didn't get any log and while checking in twilio debugger it showing error:15003

**Here my Code:**

```
<?php   
  require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
     use Twilio\Rest\Client;
    $AccountSid= 'AC04421826f5ffaa58eaefa1ba6984dac2';
    $AuthToken= 'token';
    $client = new Client($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
    try {
        $call = $client->account->calls->create(         
            // to call.
            "+9120000000",
            "+1209000001",
            array(
              "url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml",
              "method" => "GET",
              "statusCallbackMethod" => "POST",
              "statusCallback" => "localhost/twilio/log.txt",
              "statusCallbackEvent" => array(
                  "initiated", "ringing", "answered", "completed"
              )
          )
        );
        echo "Started call: " . $call->sid;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Looks like you have set the statuscallback property to point to `localhost`.

[`localhost`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) is a domain that is only reachable from your own local machine so  Twilio does not how to reach the `localhost` running on your local machine.

I'd suggest [checking out ngrok](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/10/test-your-webhooks-locally-with-ngrok.html) which is a simple tool that lets you expose the web server running on your local machine via a publicly addressable domain.

Hope that helps

Comment: Even though I tried to point my ip:72.168.10.21/events/log.txt like this am not getting result or log

Comment: In the same above you've not included the protocol portion of the URL `http://`.  Not sure if that is actually what is in your code or not, but if it is you need to make sure thats there: `http://72.168.10.21/events/log.txt`?

Comment: you can also check your Twilio logs `https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/logs/calls` and see what Twilio is logging in response to the request it makes to the URL you have configured as the StatusCallback URL.

Comment: You could also use a tool like PostMan to simulate the POST request that Twilio is making to the URL to see if your application is functioning properly.  The 15003 indicates that Twilio received a 500 category HTTP response from your application, indicating that your application encountered an error when it attempted to run.  https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/15003

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is a GET or POST request cannot be written directly  to log.txt file and the file should be hosted on a http domain.

change the following code

```
"statusCallback" => "localhost/twilio/log.txt",
```

to

```
"statusCallback" => "http://yourdomain.com/twilio/log.php",
```

as you rather need an additional file log.php which can write to log.txt

```
    <?php

$status = implode(',',$_REQUEST) ;

$handle = fopen('log.txt','a');

fwrite($handle, $status);
?>
```